# Can I use both a concrete slab and crawl space foundation?

Tags: foundation

I plan on building a large shop building on my property and while I want the main shop area to be a thick concrete slab, it would be great if I can make the adjoining rooms have a crawl space-like foundation to save on the cost of the required concrete.  Is this something that is done and would be allowed? I am learning as I go so sorry if this is a stupid question.

Comment: Are you OK with a step up (or two) into the crawlspace rooms, because the different foundation types will most likely lead to different levels.

Comment: Oh really? Why is that? Yes I believe I would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly. Split-level homes around the world (including my own) have such a scenario. Often it's a full-height basement foundation wall instead of a crawl space, but the general idea is the same. Of course, it's all subject to review and approval by an architect or engineer.

Answer (score 1):

My home is build this way. Since it is built on a slope the garage located at the lowest level has a solid concrete foundation, however the portion of the house that is not over the garage has a crawl space.